# Implement the C standard library in C++

Tags: c++, c, standard-library

Say an OS/kernel is written with C++ in mind and does not "do" any pure C style stuff, but instead exposes the C standard library built upon a full-fledged C++ standard library. Is this possible? If not, why?

PS: I know the C library is "part of C++", but let's say it's internally based on a C++-based implementation.

**Small update:** It seems I've stirred up a discussion as to what is "allowed" by my rules here. Generally speaking: the C Standard library implementation should use C++ everwhere that is possible/`Right (tm)`. I mostly think about algorithms and acting on static class objects behind the scenes. I'm not *really* excluding any language features, but instead trying to put the emphasis on a sane C++ implementation. With regards to the setjmp example, I see no reason why valid C (which would use either other pre-implemented in C++ C library parts or not use any other library functions at all) here would be violation of my "rules". If there is no counterpart in the C++ library, why debate the use of it.

Comment: I fail to see the relationship between the implementation language of a kernel and user code.

Comment: @JackN: not at all, please reread both questions. Your/my "duplicate" is specifically about pthread<->std::thread, this one about the Standard C library vs C++.

Comment: @AProgrammer: surely several library functions need to interact with the kernel to work (I'm thinking file I/O etc...)?

Comment: The interface between the kernel and user code is usually done in assembly as it requires processor specific stuff not used for the language ABI (software interrupt or SYSCALL like instruction on x86 for instance).

Comment: You obviously can provide a DLL wrapping this as official OS interface, but that interface is in no way tied to the implementation language of the kernel itself.  I'd use something very C like in order to facilitate the interfacing with all language (and thus not use things like variadic functions which are very C specific).

Comment: Surely the only way in which it can become impossible is if you judge that some particular piece of C++ code looks a bit too close to valid C in order to "count" according to your rules. In which case the implementer can just C++ it up a bit by adding more classes and/or templates until you're happy. Or not? ;-)

Comment: @Steve: in this context, C would mean using C library function calls, which are implemented in C only or C style where C++ would or could be more appropriate. I know I'm being vague here, but I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Note, I suppose, that there are some things in the C99 standard library that can't *necessarily* be implemented as libraries on just any old C++ implementation. For example if your C++ implementation doesn't have a 64 bit type, you're screwed. But I presume these OS-designers would anticipate that when building/choosing their C++ implementation.

Comment: @rubenvb: ah, I've thought of one. You can't implement `setjmp.h` as a library in C++ without using `setjmp.h`/`<csetjmp>`. But of course although `setjmp` is part of the C standard libraries (being a header), in practice it's implemented with heavy support from the compiler, it's not anything that the OS/kernel provides as a pure library. I'm not sure exactly how far you intend to conflate the roles of OS provider and C implementer - in principle an OS doesn't need to provide any part of the C standard library in order for a compiler and CRT to be written by a third party.

Comment: Another one, C++ doesn't provide any access to signals other than through the C headers, so that's another case where "implementing C libraries in terms of C++", your C++ programmers just have to give up their fine principles and do it the C way, or else give up on the idea of providing the libraries *as a library* and write the whole C environment, compiler etc.

Comment: @Steve I disagree that C++ would be any less capable of implementing those interfaces (setjmp, signals, etc). Why do you believe that to be the case?

Comment: @Judge: You can't implement them just as libraries, I mean. For example, `setjmp`/`longjmp` have to operate on the stack of the caller, so to link against it you have to do more than just respect the OS calling convention, you must also use a stack layout that it understands. That's all I really mean by it being more than just a library. Obviously you can implement the whole of C in pretty much any language. Inasmuch as this question is about anything definite, I think it's about implementing it piecemeal in a certain way that rubenvb describes as providing libraries.

Comment: @Judge: by the same token, I would say that under the rules rubenvb presents, you couldn't implement those C libraries *from C* either. The difference being that presumably he would allow calls to C standard libraries to count as "C-based", whereas he does not permit C++ code with calls to C standard libraries to count as "C++-based". I've never understood the fascination that the 'language' "C++ remove C" seems to hold for some people ;-)

Comment: @Steve Actually, setjmp/longjmp to do not unwind the stack normally. So, the library only need deal with the task control block of the underlying kernel. It really doesn't matter in the context of this question. I completely agree that is ill-defined for further debate.

Comment: @Judge: I didn't say they unwind the stack, I said they operate on it. `setjmp` in effect needs to copy its caller's state to the jump buffer, `longjmp` in effect needs to restore that state. It has nothing to do with the stack in between the caller of `setjmp` and the caller of `longjmp`.

Comment: @Steve It seems to me that if a library can snapshot the process control block then the exact details of the stack are inconsequential. The kernel does not need to know how a process is manipulating the stack to create activation records for subroutine calls. So, why would a library with access to those facilities?

Comment: @Judge: My first reasoning was that generally a PCB only contains saved register values and similar (including stack and instruction pointers), not a copy of the data actually on the stack. But now I realise maybe `setjmp` doesn't have to see the caller stack at all (at least no more than any other callee does - pc and sp to restore, a place to put the return value if that's not a register, normal stuff).

Comment: @Downvoter: what makes this a bad question?

Comment: @Steve Exactly! I probably didn't state it very well because I've never implemented `setjmp`. I was basing my statements on building small multi-tasking kernels for embedded projects. It seemed a `setjmp` would just be a context switch to an old set of PCB values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't do it, but I also see no reason why someone would use such an implementation. It's going to use a lot more memory, and be at least somewhat slower, than a normal implementation...although it might not be much worse than glibc, whose implementation of stdio is already essentially C++ anyway... (Lookup GNU `libio`... you'll be horrified.)

Comment: So it would be a lot worse, but on second thought not much worse or the same than the most popular open source C library?

Comment: @rubenvb, well put but I think I agree with R. anyway. If glibc was implemented in C++, it would be _even_ bigger. It was just a jab at how feature complete glibc is. glibc is a swiss army chainsaw tactical nuke pocket knife. :-)

Comment: People put up with glibc's size, slowness, and refusal to follow the standards because it's *what's there*. Pretty much the same reasons so many people put up with MSIE on Windows. I don't think you could write a new browser as bad as MSIE and get people to adopt it, and I don't think you could write a new standard library as bad as glibc and get people to adopt it.

Comment: Actually, I think the belief that c++ is a pessimisation of c is a myth by those who don't understand what c++ can do.

Comment: You can think that all you like, but it won't change the reality. It's almost impossible to get fail-safe code (no failure cases) using C++ idioms because virtually everything requires dynamic allocation.

Comment: There is nothing about "dynamic allocation" which is inherently slower in c++ over c, so I'm not sure what your point is.  In fact, with typesafe slabs possible, c++ could be faster.  I've posted about printf in my answer as an example where speed benefits are possible.  Can you name a single API that would necessarily be slower than c?

Comment: C admits solutions to many problems with no dynamic allocation. Usually the only way to do that in C++ is to throw out C++ idioms and write code in the ugly language that's the intersection of C and C++.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, you just reasserted your answer differently.  Do you have any specific example of a case where c++ idioms must be thrown out or a single solution c admits without dynamic allocation that c++ doesn't?  A single example would do a world better at making your point clearer, as I'm pretty lost so far.  Lifetime management is one of the places c++ excels, since it has ctors/dtors and types can be embedded using static polymorphism (generic programming) without dynamic allocation, where c would require it and a void pointer.

Comment: Any use of strings or vectors. I think the fact that you're missing is that even if such an object is created with automatic storage duration, its internal buffers must be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use tr1::array if you need automatic storage?  Dynamic char arrays usually use heap allocation in both languages, but even if you used an automatic array, you get the same behavior with a boost/tr1 array (and slightly better library support).  Why would you purposefully misuse the language features to only pessimise performance?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is possible. It would be much like one exports a C API from a library written in C++, FORTRAN, assembler or most any other language for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, c++ has the ability to be *faster* than c in many ways, due to it's ability to support many translationtime constructs like expression templates.  For this reason, c++ matrix libraries tend to be much more optimised than c, involve less temporaries, unroll loops, etc.  With new c++0x features like variant templates, the printf function, for instance, could be much faster and typesafe than a version implemented in c.  It my even be able to honor the interfaces of many c constructs and evaluate some of their arguments (like string literals) translationtime.

Unfortunately, many people think c is faster than c++ because many people use OOP to mean that all relations and usage must occur through large inheritance hierarchies, virtual dispatch, etc.  That caused some early comparisons to be completely different from what is considered good usage these days.  If you were to use virtual dispatch where it is appropriate (e.g. like filesystems in the kernel, where they build vtables through function pointers and often basically build c++ in c), you would have no pessimisation from c, and with all of the new features, can be significantly faster.

Not only is speed a possible improvement, but there are places where the *implementation* would benefit from better type safety.  There are common tricks in c (like storing data in void pointers when it must be generic) that break type safety and where c++ can provide strong error checking.  This won't always translate through the interfaces to the c library, since those have fixed typing, but it will definitely be of use to the implementers of the library and could assist in some places where it may be possible to extract more information from calls by providing "as-if" interfaces (for instance, an interface that takes a void* might be implemented as a generic interface with a concept check that the argument is implicitly convertible to void*).

I think this would be a great test of the power of c++ over c.

Answer (score 1):

Given that "pure C stuff" has such a large overlap with C++, I fail to see how you'd avoid it entirely in anything, much less an OS kernel. After all, is the `+` operation "pure C stuff"? :)

That said, you could certainly implement certain C library functions using classes and whatnot. Implement qsort using std::sort? Sure, no problem. Just don't forget your `extern "C"`.

Comment: I specifically said "C Library" do differentiate between language<->library. There is a difference, and it matters here.

Answer (score 0):

Kernels like Linux have very strict ABI, based on syscalls, ioctls, filesystems, and conforming to quite a few standards (POSIX being the major one). Since the ABI has to be stable its surface is also limited. It would be a lot of work (particularly since you need a minimally useful kernel as well), but these standards could be implemented in any language.

Edit: You mentioned the libc as well. That is not part of the kernel, and the language of the libc can be entirely unrelated to that of the kernel, thanks to the aforementioned ABI. Unlike the kernel, the libc needs to be C or have a very good ffi for C. C++ with parts in `extern C` would fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

The [LLVM C Library](https://libc.llvm.org/) is implemented in C++.
Not complete though (March 2024).

Interesting conference talk on the implementation: [The Challenges of Implementing the C Standard Library in C++ - Siva Chandra Reddy - CppNow 2023](https://youtu.be/cuVrWUGSIgM?si=5MryABbsg8V69dLr)
Interesting chicken-and-egg problem: the C++ standard library uses C library header files and most implementations make use of the C runtime.